# How to install Docker Desktop inside a Windows Server Core based container

Tags: windows-container, docker-in-docker

Haven't come across any article that says how to setup Docker in Docker for Windows (native, not WSL). Trying to build a Windows Server Core based image but from within a Windows Server Core Container. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I took some time to test this out and it turns out that it actually works:
[Windows container running inside a Windows container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6vKH.png)

The catch here is that the docker engine on the container needs to be mapped to the docker engine from the underlying container.
Here is the docker file I used:

```
    # escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

RUN powershell -Command `
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; `
        $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; `
        Invoke-WebRequest `
            -Uri https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.15.zip `
            -OutFile docker.zip; `
        Expand-Archive docker.zip -DestinationPath 'C:\Program Files'; `
        Remove-Item docker.zip -Force `
    && setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\docker"
```

Here are the commands I ran:

```
docker run -i -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine inception:v1 powershell
```

This will open a container interactively. From there, run:

```
docker run --rm mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022 cmd /c hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker Desktop should be used on Windows 10/11 only. For Server environments, which Windows containers are based on, you should install the Docker/Mirantis engine. However, I'm not entirely sure this would work and even if it does (one can try), it should not be supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Docker in docker works for Linux, so should it not be available for native Windows Containers also?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, from @vinicius response you might need to specify --network flag when building the image i.e docker build --network="Default Switch"  -t inception:v1 .